# Clear Row Data Based on Value in Google Sheet ( Specific Data ) appscript

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api, spreadsheet

I am looking for a base on value clear specific row content/data and then hide row.

type value "Done" in { F Col } Clear Value of { E , C Col }

when everything  is done then hide row.

[image]

```
function ClearContentThenHideRow() {
  var s = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Main');
  s.showRows(1, s.getMaxRows());
  
  s.getRange('F:F')
    .getValues()
    .forEach( function (r, i) {
    if (r[0] == 'Done') 
      //sheet.getRange(["C:C","E:E"]).clearContent(); // clear content not working 
      s.hideRows(i + 1);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Modification points:

- About `sheet.getRange(["C:C","E:E"]).clearContent();`,

  - `sheet` is not declared.
  - When you want to use the range list, please use `getRangeList()`.
- When `s.getRange('F1:F' + s.getLastRow())` is used instead of `s.getRange('F:F')`, I thought that the process cost will be able to be reduced a little.

When above points are reflected to your script, it becomes as follows.

#### Modified script:

```
function ClearContentThenHideRow() {
  var s = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Main');
  // s.showRows(1, s.getMaxRows()); <--- removed
  s.getRange('F1:F' + s.getLastRow())
    .getValues()
    .forEach(function (r, i) {
      if (r[0] == 'Done') {
        s.getRangeList(["C" + (i + 1), "E" + (i + 1)]).clearContent();
        s.hideRows(i + 1);
      }
    });
}
```

#### Reference:

- [getRangeList(a1Notations) of Class Sheet](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getrangelista1notations)

Comment: Code run fine. But something going wrong, When I am write Done in "F COL" it is runs script and unhide previous all row then hide all current rows. I mean its flashing all hide row and then hide all rows again and again.

Comment: @Manish S Thank you for replying. I apologize for the inconvenience. In your script, `s.showRows(1, s.getMaxRows())` is used. From your script, I thought that you are required to be used. But I think that this might be the reason of your current issue. For example, is to remove it the same direction you expect? For this, I updated my answer. Could you please confirm it? If that was not the direction you expect, I apologize again.